# Laravel Assign User to Shop in Create Form

Tags: mysql, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-7

I've form to add new users and assign user to Shop

Also, I've user_id field in Shop Table

What am i trying to do is:

in create form there will be a select box with all Shops name that doesn't have user id

so i want to assign user to selected Shop from the select box

Any Ideas?

Store Function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'name'         => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'          => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password'          => 'required|string|min:8',
    ));
    $password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->save();

    return redirect('admin/users')->with('success', 'user is successfully saved');
}
```

View

```
<form action="{{route('users.store')}}" method="post">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('post')
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="wizard-validation-classic-firstname">Name</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="wizard-validation-classic-firstname" name="name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="wizard-validation-classic-lastname">E-mail</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="wizard-validation-classic-lastname" name="email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="wizard-validation-classic-lastname">password</label>

                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="password">

                                </div>

                                </form>
```

Comment: @TalhaF. actually no

Comment: Then retag your queation

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote here is okay, but in create methood of the controller you have to grab the shops with no user_id and pass those shops as parameter in create view file to populate them in the selectbox field (the view you showed above) the code snippet of create() method should be something like this

```
function  create () {
$shops = Shop::where('user_id',NULL)->get();
 return view('create', ['shops' => $shops]);
}
```

in create view add this field ,

```
<select name="shop_id">
    @foreach($shops as $shop)
    <option value="{{ $shop->id }}">{{ $shop->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

style the field as per your need.

Now after submitting the form in store() method , the $request will contain the 'shop_id' with  the value selected by the user, you can use this value to save the user_id in shop table like the code below.

place this code after user being saved.

```
$user->save();//this is where you saved the user
//This is the code to save user_id in shop table
//check if user is created successfully
if( $user ) {
Shop::where('id', $request->shop_id)->update(array('user_id' => $user->id));
}
```

Though I did not test the code complete from my end, but this is pretty much the thing and should be working.